# Install the MSI to GAC the BizTalk Application DLL using Powershell

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-deployment

My task is to Deploy an Existing BizTalk Application using PowerShell Script. I use multiple commands to import the msi and bindings. When i install the MSI manually, I can see the dll GACed with latest time. But, when I do it with the PowerShell, it says installed but the dll is not updated with the latest time.

The PS command is:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i    C:\MyFolder\XmlCarrier.msi /qn /passive" -Wait
```

Please help .

Comment: Are you launching PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Yes am running it as Administrator.

Comment: Add the `/l*v xmlcarrier.log` parameter to your msiexec command line, and examine the log.

Comment: I got this:   MSI (s) (B4:FC) [07:20:48:683]: Product: XmlCarrier -- Configuration completed successfully.

MSI (s) (B4:FC) [07:20:48:683]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: XmlCarrier. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

Comment: It looks like the MSI is already installed? What if you remove it and install it again?

Comment: Yes, i can remove and install it again manually. But am wondering how to do that using powershell..